# Selecting certain fields in layer using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have a layer in geodatabase, and I want to use SelectLayerByAttribute to select certain fields in this layer.

Then, use CopyFeature to output those fields to a new shapefile.

for example:

```
layer = I created in gdb

selection_type = 'NEW_SELECTION'

SelectedFields = """ Field_name = 'XXXX' """

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, selection_type, SelectedFields)
```

But, my where_clause part always invalid.

anyone can help me get the correct SQL expression?

Comment: Are you really using the text `Field_name`  in your where clause and trying to select values that are really XXXX? If not you need to show us the true query for anyone to help.

Comment: in addition to @Hornbydd comments, also `layer = I created in gdb` - a gdb doesn't have layers, it has feature classes.  Are you referring to a layer or a feature class?  What error message are you getting? Please include that error message in full

Answer (score 2):

See this post:  [Using "IN" for SQL statement in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214990/using-in-for-sql-staement-in-python)

Your current code returns this for the expression:  "Field = 'XXXX' "

You need this in your expression (assuming your using shapefiles):  "Field"= 'XXXX'

For GDB feature class, you need this:  Field = 'XXXX'

You also need a feature layer for the selection.

Try this instead of your code:

```
layer = I created in gdb

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer,"layer")

selection_type = 'NEW_SELECTION'

SelectedField = '\"Field\"' #for shapefile.  If gdb change to "Field"

Expression = SelectedField + '=' + "\'XXXX\'"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", selection_type, Expression)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Add Field Delimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) to take away some guessing with the " or ' signs:

> Adds field delimiters to a field name to allow for use in SQL
>   expressions.  The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ
>   depending on the format of the queried data. For instance, file
>   geodatabases and shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal
>   geodatabases use square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases
>   don't use field delimiters. The function can take away the guess work
>   in ensuring that the field delimiters used with your SQL expression
>   are the correct ones.

Example:

```
import arcpy

in_feature_class = r'C:\TEST.gdb\polygons'
out_fc = r'C:\TEST.gdb\polygon_selection'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=in_feature_class, out_layer='fclyr') #a where clause is also possible in MakeFeatureLayer_management

sqlexp = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource='fclyr', field= 'Textfield')

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='fclyr', selection_type='NEW_SELECTION', where_clause=sqlexp + "= 'fdssdf'")

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='fclyr', out_feature_class=out_fc)
```