# Using "IN" for SQL statement in Python

Tags: arcpy, sql, error-000358

I'm selecting all records and then removing certain values from this selection in a Python script. I've succeeded using a for loop in a SearchCursor to remove records from the selection but it is very slow. Is there anyway to remove the records all at once using "IN" like how this would work in the field calculator

```
SELECT * FROM FeatureClass WHERE Field IN ('a', 'f', 'l')
```

This is what I have so far:

```
gRoutes =  ('R10T', 'R10TBP', 'R10TWP', 'R20T', 'R20TBP', 'R20TWP', 'R32T', 'R32TBP', 'R32TWP', 'R45T', 'R45TBY', 'R45TBP', 'R45TWP', 'R64T', 'R64TBP', 'R64TWP', 'R96T', 'R96TBP', 'R96TWP', 'R10TBY', 'R20TBY', 'R32TBY', 'R64TBY', 'R96TBY')

# field name
QF1 = "Product_Code"

WC1 = '"' + QF1 + '" IN ' + "'" + gRoutes + "'"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layerFC","REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION", WC1)
```

This is what the WC1 expression prints as:

```
'"Product_Code" IN \'[\'R10T\', \'R10TBP\', \'R10TWP\', \'R20T\', \'R20TBP\', \'R20TWP\', \'R32T\', \'R32TBP\', \'R32TWP\', \'R45T\', \'R45TBY\', \'R45TBP\', \'R45TWP\', \'R64T\', \'R64TBP\', \'R64TWP\', \'R96T\', \'R96TBP\', \'R96TWP\', \'R10TBY\', \'R20TBY\', \'R32TBY\', \'R64TBY\', \'R96TBY\']\''
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Start Time: Thu Oct 20 14:59:48 2016
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
Failed at Thu Oct 20 14:59:48 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.02 seconds)
```

Comment: It looks like the gRoutes is a becoming a Python list. You don't want this. It should be a string so add Double quotes outside the parenthesis where you are defining gRoutes.

Comment: Thanks klewis. Still getting "Error 000358 Invalid Expression". Same result when printing WC1. Seems as if it is still being converted to python list.

Comment: [Previous Q&As with the same error](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000358) may be worth reviewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (SQL in python is kind of annoying sometimes):

```
gRoutes =  '(\'R10T\', \'R10TBP\', \'R10TWP\', \'R20T\', \'R20TBP\', \'R20TWP\', \'R32T\', \'R32TBP\', \'R32TWP\', \'R45T\', \'R45TBY\', \'R45TBP\', \'R45TWP\', \'R64T\', \'R64TBP\', \'R64TWP\', \'R96T\', \'R96TBP\', \'R96TWP\', \'R10TBY\', \'R20TBY\', \'R32TBY\', \'R64TBY\', \'R96TBY\')'

# field name
QF1 = '\"Product_Code\"'

WC1 = QF1 + ' IN ' + gRoutes

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layerFC","REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION", WC1)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Any idea why the slashes are required? WC1 still prints out the same but the values were removed and a million times faster.

Comment: The backslashes escape the single quotes so they're not read by Python (in the case of gRoutes not read as separate list elements).  When you're using reserved characters but want them to appear, you have to escape them.  And SQL is pretty picky about how you quote stuff (but you know that already).

Answer (score 3):

This is why Python allows both quotes and apostrophes.   Best practice would use them and a `.format()` to improve readability:

```
gRoutes = "'R10T', 'R10TBP', 'R10TWP', 'R20T', 'R20TBP', 'R20TWP', 'R32T', 'R32TBP', 'R32TWP', 'R45T', 'R45TBY', 'R45TBP', 'R45TWP', 'R64T', 'R64TBP', 'R64TWP', 'R96T', 'R96TBP', 'R96TWP', 'R10TBY', 'R20TBY', 'R32TBY', 'R64TBY', 'R96TBY'"
WC1 = '"Product_Code" IN ({:s})'.format(gRoutes)
```

You can even compile the members as a Python list or array, then expand at runtime (clipping the opening and closing parens/braces):

```
gRoutes = ( 'R10T', 'R10TBP', 'R10TWP', 'R20T', 'R20TBP', 'R20TWP', 'R32T', 'R32TBP', 'R32TWP', 'R45T', 'R45TBY', 'R45TBP', 'R45TWP', 'R64T', 'R64TBP', 'R64TWP', 'R96T', 'R96TBP', 'R96TWP', 'R10TBY', 'R20TBY', 'R32TBY', 'R64TBY', 'R96TBY' )
WC1 = '"Product_Code" IN ({:s})'.format(str(gRoutes)[1:-1])
```

Be sure to confirm that the `IN` list doesn't exceed the RDBMS's maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Prepping IN strings for SQL can be a pain. Simplest way to process your `gRoutes` list would be something like

```
gRoutes = "\', \'".join(gRoutes)
gRoutes = "\'{}\'".format(gRoutes)
```

so

```
WC1 = "{} IN ({})".format(QF1, gRoutes)
```

or z could include your bracket characters, `"(\'{}\')".format(y)` and `WC1` could skip them.